# How do I query the sales/order_collection to shipping_lastname

Tags: collection, sales-order

I'm trying to query the database and build a page which is outside of the admin console.
It's a quick page to show what products my manufacturing guys need to make.

I've managed to put this together (see below), but for some reason I can't extract the shipping_lastname and shipping_firstname from the array.

Anyone know how I can do this in my code below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
    $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_street', 'order_address/street', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_company', 'order_address/company', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'order_address/city', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'order_address/region', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country', 'order_address/country_id', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'order_address/postcode', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'order_address/telephone', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_fax', 'order_address/fax', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_street', 'order_address/street', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_company', 'order_address/company', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_city', 'order_address/city', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_region', 'order_address/region', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_country', 'order_address/country_id', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_postcode', 'order_address/postcode', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_telephone', 'order_address/telephone', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_fax', 'order_address/fax', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')

        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array("in" => array(
            'processing')
            ))

        ->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'asc')
        ->load();

        echo '<table cellpadding="5">';
        echo '<tr><td>Order No</td><td>Name</td><td>SKU</td><td>Product</td><td align="center">Qty</td></tr>';
        foreach($orders as $order)
        {   
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach($items as $item){
                $orderno    = $order->getIncrementId();
                $lastname   = $order->getData('order_address');             // <<-- what do I need to put here to get the shipping_lastname field conents
            $sku            = $item->getSku();
            $product    = $item->getName();
            $qty            = number_format($item->getQtyOrdered());

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$order->getIncrementId().'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$lastname.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$sku.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$product.'</td>';
            echo '<td align="center">'.$qty.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        }
        echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You fell into a trap. `joinAttribute()` does exactly [nothing](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Collection/Abstract.php#L149-165) in sales models:

```
/**
 * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
 *
 * @todo implement join functionality if necessary
 *
 * @param string $alias
 * @param string $attribute
 * @param string $bind
 * @param string $filter
 * @param string $joinType
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract
 */
public function joinAttribute($alias, $attribute, $bind, $filter = null, $joinType = 'inner', $storeId = null)
{
    return $this;
}
```

The comment already hints at it: the method is only there for historical reasons because in older Magento versions (I think until around 1.2 or 1.3) the sales models (order, quote etc.) were EAV models just like products, categories and customers. The class hierarchy and table names starting with `sales_flat_` (as in flat index) still look like EAV but not all EAV features could be mapped to the flat table structure eventually.

### Easy but unperformant solution:

If you don't care about performance, you could call `$order->getShippingAddress()->getLastname()`, which results in an additional database query per order.

### Performant solution:

Craft your joins manually with the `Zend_Db_Select` interface:

```
$orders->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('shipping' => 'order_address'),      // alias => table
    'shipping.address_id=shipping_address_id', // join condition
    array(                                     // fields to select (alias => column)
        'shipping_firstname' => 'firstname',
        'shipping_lastname' => 'lastname'));
);
```

and then access the fields by the aliases defined above:

```
$order->getData('shipping_firstname');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use addFieldToSort('shipping_lastname') to sort your collection on lastname.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
                ->join(
                    array('soa' => 'sales/order_address'),
                   'soa.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soa.address_type = "billing"', 
                    array('soa.firstname','soa.lastname', 'soa.street')' 
                 ), null,'left')
```